# PHP within a variable that contains HTML within another variable

Tags: php, wordpress

I'd like to add a variable that holds a function ( be it WordPress or a custom function ) within HTML that's within another variable. The problem is that when I concatenate it pops outside of the div container in the front end, where I need it to be inside the container.

For example shown here, I'd like "$stay_put" or PHP in general to be generated in these divs:

```
function sort_sections( $sections ) {
      $sections = explode(',', $sections);
      $output = '';
      /* $stay put needs to be able to hold any function */
      $stay_put = wp_list_pages();
      if ( empty( $sections ) ) {
          return $output;
      }
      foreach( $sections as $section ) {
        switch ( $section ) {
        case 'section_a':
            $output .= '<div>Section A</div>';
            break;
        case 'section_b':
            $output .= '<div>Section B</div>';
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
      }
      return $output;
  }
```

What I came up with but displays variable outside container :

```
$stay_put

foreach( $sections as $section ) {
  switch ( $section ) {
  case 'section_a':
      $output .= '<div>' . $stay_put . '</div>';
      break;
  case 'section_b':
      $output .= '<div>' . $stay_put . '</div>';
      break;
  default:
      break;
  }
}
```

If any one can help,

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT: Solution**

```
function render_sections( $sections ) {
      $sections = explode(',', $sections);
      $output = '';
      $stay_put = wp_list_pages(['echo' => false]);
      if ( empty( $sections ) ) {
          return $output;
      }
      foreach( $sections as $section ) {
        switch ( $section ) {
        case 'section_a':
            $output .= '<div>Section A';
            $output .= $stay_put;
            $output .= '</div>';
            break;
        case 'section_b':
            $output .= '<div>Section B';
            $output .= $stay_put;
            $output .= '</div>';
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
      }
      return $output;
  }
```

Comment: What does `$stay_put` holds?

Comment: In this case I wanted a WP function: $stay_put = wp_list_pages(). However I'd like it to be able to call any regular function from that variable.

Comment: And what's the output? Can you update that in your question?

Comment: It holds ' '; and code updated for clarity.

Comment: @thx1138 can you show how your showing that variable `$output`

Comment: @thx1138 `$stay_put needs to be able to hold any function` : Then it should be like this `$stay_put='wp_list_pages()';` if variable `$stay_put` is going to hold return value of `wp_list_pages` function then it should be like this `$stay_put=wp_list_pages();`

 I'm not sure how you are using variable `$output`. If you are using php variable/function in between html then it should be like this  `<div><?php wp_list_pages();?></div>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the main problem with your example code is that you want to return the output, but the call to `wp_list_pages` does not return the required information, but directly echos it. If you want to add the result of `wp_list_pages` to your output, you have to add a parameter to `wp_list_pages`. According to the [wordpress documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_pages/), you have to set `echo` to `false`.

To add it after the div of each section, please see the following code:

```
function render_sections( $sections ) {
      $sections = explode(',', $sections);
      $output = '';
      $stay_put = wp_list_pages(['echo' => false);
      if ( empty( $sections ) ) {
          return $output;
      }
      foreach( $sections as $section ) {
        switch ( $section ) {
        case 'section_a':
            $output .= "<div>Section A</div>';
            $output .= $stay_put;
            break;
        case 'section_b':
            $output .= '<div>Section B</div>';
            $output .= $stay_put;
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
      }
      return $output;
  }
```

Please note that I have change the function name from `sort_sections` to `render_sections` as this seems to be more closely describing its functionality (clean code).